# How to define explicit operator in F#?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

How do you implement the equivalent of C#'s `explicit` operator in F#? Is it supported?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just implement an `op_Explicit` static member like

```
type SomeType() =
    static member op_Explicit(source: SomeType) : int =
        1
```

and then you can use a corresponding F# explicit conversion operator like

```
SomeType() |> int
```

you can see a bit into how this works by noting the static member constraint on the type signature of `int`

```
^a -> int when  ^a : (static member op_Explicit :  ^a -> int)
```

Comment: You can define `op_Implicit` member for implicit operator